# Black screen after unlock screen os 6

Tags: black-screen

When i use external monitor during unlocking phase, I have black screen without possibility to go over.
Only Power off with power button can help.
OS: E6
Patch: all until now
It happens with USBC - HDMI connection

Comment: For me it's not working in general. I found a related issue: https://github.com/elementary/plymouth-theme/issues/17