# Elementaryos-6 Locking the screen and unlocking the screen returns to black screen with a cursor

Tags: black-screen

My issue is very similar to [Black screen after unlock screen os 6](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28623/black-screen-after-unlock-screen-os-6)

Just locking the screen and unlocking it is not returning to the desktop.
Here is what I got:

[image: hardware]

And checking the `dmesg` following line caught my attention:

```
traps: pool-io.element[34441] trap int3 ip:9fac32u543878 error:0 in ibglig-2.0.so.0.6400.6
```

How can I fix this issue and get the desktop after unlocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions provided worked for me.

1. https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/165
2. https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/1126

Taking a backup of my work files and `reinstalling` `elmentaryos` fixed the issue.